# How can I get the parent node within yaml.loader add_contructor?

Tags: python, yaml

I am crafting a YAML template that will allow the use of specific `!Tags`.  The way to handle tags when loading a YAML file in python is to add a constructor: `yaml.add_constructor`.  I would like to add a ScalarNode constructor, but the return value should be based upon data that would be present as a sibling of the node being evaluated.

```py
def sibling_constructor(loader, node):
    value = loader.construct_scalar(node)
    # How to get parent node's child nodes?
    return value + ' are dangerous.'

yaml.add_constructor('!Sibling', sibling_constructor)    
return yaml.load(myFile)
```

Yaml:

```
Thing:
  ParentThing:
    Child1: Fast cars
    Child2: Slow cars
    Child3: !Sibling Child1
```

Once the YAML file is processed, I would expect the in-memory dictionary to appear something like this:

```
{
  'Thing': {
    'ParentThing': {
        'Child1': 'Fast cars',
        'Child2': 'Slow cars',
        'Child3': 'Fast cars are dangerous.'
    }
  }
}
```

Is there functionality within the YAML module to get the parent node?  If not, how might I traverse the dictionary to get the parent and sibling nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no functionality in the YAML module to access sibling or the
parent from within `sibling_constructor` as it would have to be available through 
the parameter `loader` or `node`.

The `node` parameter is a `Node` instance and its
[attributes](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml/src/75c831644aa26f12ff33ac81180fbaa23b81d4bb/nodes.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#nodes.py-15):`tag`,
`value`, `start_mark`, `end_mark`, `comment`, `anchor` contain no context information (the `mark`s contain pointers into the source
stream, `comment` a possible end-of-line comment on that line).

That the `loader` parameter doesn't have this information is far less
clear, as it is much more complex data-structure. But what you probably
don't realise is that the construction process is depth
first, so your parent has not been constructed, and therefor there is
no entry-point to the data-structure loaded from YAML, until the last node is processed, 
after which its parent can be fully created, then its parent
etc. until the recursion ends and the constructed data returned from
the `load()` function.

---

But not all hope is lost, if you use the default round-trip loader, you have access
to the tag without needing to add a constructor, so you can easily do a post-processing pass.
Assuming your input is in a file `input.yaml`:

```
import sys
from pprint import pprint
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

input_path = Path('input.yaml')

def sibling(d):
    # recurse into a data structure loaded from YAML
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            try:
                if v._yaml_tag.value == '!Sibling':
                    d[k] = d[v.value] + ' are dangerous.'
            except (AttributeError, ):
                pass
            sibling(v)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for item in d:
            sibling(item)



yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(input_path)
sibling(data)

pprint(data)
print('-------')
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

gives:

```
{'Thing': {'ParentThing': {'Child1': 'Fast cars',
                           'Child2': 'Slow cars',
                           'Child3': 'Fast cars are dangerous.'}}}
-------
Thing:
  ParentThing:
    Child1: Fast cars
    Child2: Slow cars
    Child3: Fast cars are dangerous.
```

---

Although it is possible to register a new method that constructs a
mapping (`construct_yaml_map`), and attaches the `dict` being
constructed to the `Constructor` instance, this `dict`, however, gets
updated in one go, when all the mapping's key/value pairs have been
resolved:

```
def construct_yaml_map(self, node):
    data = self.yaml_base_dict_type()  # type: Dict[Any, Any]
    self._tw_current_dict = data
    yield data
    value = self.construct_mapping(node)
    data.update(value)

ruamel.yaml.SafeConstructor.add_constructor(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:map', construct_yaml_map)

yaml.add_constructor('!Sibling', sibling_constructor, constructor=ruamel.yaml.SafeConstructor)
return yaml.safe_load(myFile)
```

so when you add the above to your code and your `sibling_constructor` would be called `loader._tw_current_dict` is available, but empty.

(You should be using the `SafeLoader`, there is no need to make everything unsafe by using the old `load` method inherited from PyYAML)

You might be able to hook into `construct_mapping`, I briefly tried
and got stuck (and I do claim to be fairly familiar with the YAML module's source code).

---

One thing you might consider is changing your input YAML to look like:

```
Thing:
  ParentThing:
    Child1: &child Fast cars
    Child2: Slow cars
    Child3: !Sibling *child
```

i.e. using the normal referncing mechanism in YAML of anchors and aliases. That alias
`*child` of course **can** be resolved at the moment the value for `Child3` gets created.

Comment: Thank you @Anthon!  I found a similar stack thread you posted informing of the same limitation: [yaml-use-key-or-parent-key-as-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33065790/yaml-use-key-or-parent-key-as-value). I like your suggestion to use a class to resolve during post processing using `__repr__`. That works!  I'll take a look at using ruamel as well, as I am doing some crazy merges.

Comment: @ToddWorden I should review my own answers here on [so] %-) I sometimes vaguely remember having solved a similar issue as asked, but I am obviously to lazy to see if it was somewhere in my own work using YAML, or an answer here on SO, and just code away a new answer....